"immer noch" meaning "still"

Wir waren gut integriert, aber es war immer noch schwierig.
We were well integrated, but it was still difficult. (Duolingo's translation)

This is a sentence Duolingo just showed me, along with its English translation. I learned immer noch as meaning "still". But the tricky thing is English "still" has a plethora of meanings and connotations. The context of the English sentence seems to suggest the sense "nevertheless, all the same", as in "The weather was cold and wet. Still, we had a great time." (namely definition adverb 4 in Merriam Webster's entry) But I wonder if the German term immer noch actually carries that meaning, because of the inclusion of the temporal word "immer". I assume immer noch would be along the lines of "up until this point" or "up until the point of reference in context" or as Cambridge suggests "up to and including the present time, or the time mentioned previously", thus corresponding only to sense 3 in M-W's definition of "still". (I guess this denotation of still could apply in the English sentence but it seems less intuitive and it wouldn't be my first guess.)
Duden's definition of immer noch reads "nach wie vor" which also seems to be a temporal expression (literally "like before" I think?)
So can immer noch mean "nevertheless"?

The English is ambiguous and would need to be rephrased if the meaning isn't clear from the surrounding context. Either "We were well integrated, but it was difficult despite that." or "We were well integrated, but it continued to be difficult." So the question is whether the German is equally ambiguous. It's possible that the English is the original and the German is the translation.

@RDBury To me it seems as if this is another case where German leaves temporal and causal/conditional relation mingled, as with wenn which may be if or when. If, after something changes (now well integrated), another thing continues to persist (it's difficult), obviously the persisting thing persists in spite of the change, and of course after the change. German simply conflates the two.

Immer noch has a temporal meaning. So the German sentence could also be translated to "Even after being well integrated, it was [still] difficult."
For nonetheless, other German words would be used, such as trotzdem, dennoch, or nichtsdestoweniger.

So you’re saying that immer noch is only used temporally, to denote an unexpected retention of a previous state, and not to indicate an unexpected outcome that does not include retaining a previous state? So, for example, “He fell, but he still caught the ball” could not be Er ist gefallen, aber er hat immer noch den Ball gefangen, but must be Er ist gefallen, aber er hat trotzdem/dennoch/etc. den Ball gefangen (or however you want to phrase it exactly, but not with immer noch)?

Er ist gefallen, aber er hat immer noch den Ball gefangen is possible, but this usage of immer noch is somewhat special. It is not generally possible to exchange trotzdem and immer noch. For example, the sentences Er war krank, ist aber trotzdem zur Schule gegangen and Er war krank, ist aber immer noch zur Schule gegangen slightly differ in meaning. The immer noch in the second sentence would be understood as temporal (He was sick, but nonetheless he was going to school vs. He was sick, but continued to go to school).

@JanusBahsJacquet To me your ball catching example is perfect for the slightly different meaning. Using 'immer noch' might be technically correct but sounds awkward to me, precisely because it is not temporal. Using trotzdem or dennoch sounds much better.

"Wir waren nun geschieden, aber er machte mir immer noch das Leben schwer." "So sehr ich mich auch bemühte, es war immer noch nicht gut genug." "Ich habe es euch schon dreimal verboten, aber ihr tut es immer noch."  There is clearly a contradiction conveyed. German is simply a bit fuzzy here, as with the temporal/conditional fuzziness of wenn.


So can immer noch mean "nevertheless"?

Yes, sometimes, probably, depending on context.
"immer noch" is a phrase consisting of "immer" (always) and "noch", a mood particle. The meaning of the phrase is:

something is the case/happens
then some other thing happens and one might expect that it changed the original thing
despite this implicit expectation the original something still is the case/happens.

Here is an example:

Wir tun es immer noch.


we did it in the past
since then time has passed (this is the other thing happening) and one might expect we do "it" differently (or not at all any more) since then, but
no, we still do "it".

So, "immer noch" always carries that implication that one might expect the thing to be/be done/... differently, but that isn't the case.

Wir machen das so seit hundert Jahren.

We do it like that for a hundred years. There is no implication of a thwarted expectation, just a factual statement.

Wir machen das immer noch so.

We still do it like that. This implicitly says that one might have expected us to do it differently (or not at all any more), but - against this expectation - this is not the case. Something might have happened, but we do it that way nevertheless.
Addendum:
Piqued by the discussion in the comments a few words about "other" meanings of "immer noch":
German has a flexible word order (what a stunning new revelation, no?) and the upshot is that "immer noch" might not mean the phrase I described above but simply be a different order for "noch immer". The example cited:

Er hat immer noch den Ball gefangen.

is just a (worded in reverse order to mark it) "noch immer":

Er hat noch immer den Ball gefangen.

This is different from the phrase described above even though it consists of the same words. It expresses the opinion that something was the case every time up to now and therefore is expected to be the same the next time.
In the example above: he caught the ball every time - up to now - is the literal meaning, but the implication is that he is expected to continue to do so and hence catch the next ball too. A real-life conversation might go:

Q: Ist der Torschuß nicht ziemlich gefährlich?
A: Der Tormann hat den Ball noch immer gefangen.

To put extra emphasis on this expectation one could reverse the word order and use "immer noch" instead of "noch immer", but this is still a different phrase and not the "genuine" immer noch.
